# Button click pass argument to callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code , very simple , not working :

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#NetworkSearch', NetworkMarketSearching("NETWORK"));
    $(document).on('click', '#MarketSearch', NetworkMarketSearching("MARKET"));
    $(document).on('click', '#CableSearch', NetworkMarketSearching("CABLE"));
});
```

you can see -  I am very simply using `.on()` to make `NetworkMarketSearching()` fire from a click, here is the function.  This function works just fine on its own if called from the console.

```
function NetworkMarketSearching(types) {
    var name, searchType;
    if (types == 'NETWORK') { name = $('#NetworkName').val(); searchType = 0; }
    else if (types == 'MARKET') { name = $('#MarketName').val(); searchType = 1; }
    else if (types == 'CABLE') {name = $('#CableName').val();searchType = 2;}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Talent_/Common/NetworkMarketSearch',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'name': name, 'searchType': searchType },
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
}
```

The error is 'undefined is not a function'  it repeatedly happens when putting `NetworkMarketSearching('NETWORK')` in the line of `.on('click', ...`

Comment: Do you mean the error occurs only when you click on DOM element with id = NetworkSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#NetworkSearch', function() { NetworkMarketSearching("NETWORK"); });
    $(document).on('click', '#MarketSearch', function() { NetworkMarketSearching("MARKET"); });
    $(document).on('click', '#CableSearch', function() { NetworkMarketSearching("CABLE"); });
});
```

The click method doessnt support the string parameter, it expects the event object parameter.

Comment: You should explain why, the fact that the OP is calling the function and assigning its return result (undefined) as the callback.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you were trying to say - it did work though

Comment: for more info take a look at this: http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object

Comment: @ScottSelby: Refer this link: http://api.jquery.com/on/ . You'll know the reason for it. It has some examples which illustrates what Andy G was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

This `NetworkMarketSearching("NETWORK")` calls the function immediately and attempts to assign its return result (which is undefined) as the callback.

You can use the `data` argument to pass information to your function calls:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#NetworkSearch', { types: 'NETWORK' }, NetworkMarketSearching);
    $(document).on('click', '#MarketSearch', { types: 'MARKET' }, NetworkMarketSearching);
    $(document).on('click', '#CableSearch', { types: 'CABLE' }, NetworkMarketSearching);
});
```

Then the function definition would be:

```
function NetworkMarketSearching(event) {
```

and, within the function, the types would be referenced as

```
event.data.types
```

This is the way the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) specify passing arguments to the callback, but it can be done also with an inline anonymous function. That is to say, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#NetworkSearch', function () {
        NetworkMarketSearching('NETWORK');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#MarketSearch', function () {
        NetworkMarketSearching('MARKET');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#CableSearch', function () {
        NetworkMarketSearching('CABLE');
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice explaination, couldn't have said it myself.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the function exists at the moment you call it?

Try go simple, use this sample of jquery site (http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
function notify() {
  alert( "clicked" );
}
$( "button" ).on( "click", notify );
```

then you pass a parameter, if it works you move to your code.

Comment: the function does exist , the other answer worked , it was - as I suspected - something to do with the string parameter